# Throwing exceptions with empty result sets in Hibernate Panache

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a few `GET` calls in my Quarkus REST application that accept an ID.

```
/rest/v1/employee/{id}/id
```

I'm using the [active record pattern](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#solution-1-using-the-active-record-pattern) to deal with the database requests. Coming from Spring, the `JdbcTemplate` would throw an exception any time the result set was empty. I would catch this exception using `ControllerAdvice` and throw the appropriate response code (in this case, 404). This applied to all other exceptions as well.

Is there any way to configure Panache / Hibernate to throw exceptions on empty result sets? Right now, I have to manually check to see if the result is empty / null and then throw the appropriate exception.

For example, this is what I have to do now:

```
@GET
@Path("/employee/{id}/id")
public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    Employee employee = Employee.findById(id);

    if (employee == null) {
        throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException("No results found");
    }

    return Employee.findById(id);
}
```

When I would rather catch the exception in an exception handler and simply return the call to `findById(...)`:

```
@GET
@Path("/employee/{id}/id")
public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return Employee.findById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`findById` will use `EntityManager.find()` behind the scenes which returns null if the entity is not found. You could use `findByIdOptional` and use it like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/employee/{id}/id")
public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return Employee.findByIdOptional(id).orElseThrow(EmptyResultDataAccessException::new);
}
```

Comment: I like this but it only applies to `findById`.

Comment: For the query methods you can use something similar.